# Rearrange a list of items in an array based on different patterns using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I recently wrote a similar question, but removed it because the question itself was not clear and sufficiently descriptive. So here goes:

I’m trying to rearrange a list of items in an array based on different patterns. For example, let’s say we have an array that looks like this:

```
var Items = ['l','w','m','m','w','h','l','w','m','m','w','h','l','w','h'];
```

Now, I would like to rearrange the items to map any of these patterns:

```
var Patterns = ['l', 'ww', 'hh' , 'wmm', 'mmw', 'hmm', 'mmh', 'mmmm'];
```

I don’t want to pick the items randomly, I would like to keep the chronological hierarchy of the items as close as possible, reading from left to right. Also, the pattern array is prioritized reading from left to right. ('l' is more important than 'ww' and so on.)

#### I’ll try to describe the process, step by step:

If we use the above Items array, we would like to check the first item: Items[0] and compare it to the Patterns array.

So:

**Step 1.** Items[0] (l) matches Patterns[0] (**l**) perfectly, so stop searching for more pattern combination and save this and continue from here.

```
Output: l, …
```

**Step 2.** Items[1] (w) matches Patterns[1] (**w** w) and Patterns[3] (**w** mm), continue searching since all pattern combinations that starts with or includes a 'w' is combined with another character.

**Step 3** *(continuing from Step 2)*. Items[1] (w) + Items[2] (m) matches Patterns[3] (**wm** m). Continue since Patterns[3] includes 3 characters (wmm)

**Step 4** *(continuing from Step 3)*. Items[1] (w) + Items[2] (m) + Items[3] (m) matches Patterns[3] (**wmm**). Close and save since it's a perfect match.

```
Output: l, w, m, m, …
```

**Step 5.** Items[4] (w) matches Patterns[1] (**w** w) and Patterns[3] (**w** mm), continue searching since all pattern combinations that starts with or includes a 'w' is combined with another character.

**Step 6.** *(continuing from Step 5)*. Items[5] (h) does not match any pattern combinations starting with 'w' (previous step) so: grab and move the nearest 'w' which in this case is Items[7] and combine with Items[4] (previous step) since it's a match of Patterns[1] (**ww**) and Patterns[1] is more important (prioritized) than Patterns[3] because we read the array from left to right.

```
Output: l, w, m, m, w, w, …
```

Continue...

---

There might be impossible to combine the last or the two characters from the Items array, not sure. Here is the complete output (if my counting is correct) of the above Items array after steping thru all combinations:

```
Output: l, w, m, m, w, w, h, h, l, m, m, w, l, w, h
```

Do anyone know how this might be done using Javascript?

Comment: In step 6, could you explain why you move to the nearest `w`, and not try the `l` next to the `h` first?

Comment: Because we’ve found "w" (Items[4]) from the first char in both Patterns[1] and Patterns[3], so we try complete from there.

Comment: If `Patterns` had an extra element `wl` at the end, would step 6 match `wl` or still match `ww`?

Comment: if 'wl' was listed before 'ww' in the Patterns array, it would be more prio than 'ww'.

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand it yet, but the second match is `wmm` (1, 2, 3) while `ww` (1, 4) has higher priority. With that logic, if `wl` is at the **end** of the patterns array, then step 6 would match `wl` even though it has lower priority. Is that correct?

Comment: I don’t completely understand what you’re asking to be honest ;) Tha patterns that are in the Patterns array are what they are. So, adding "wl" to it might not be a solution. This is all really hard to explain... sorry for that.

Comment: Let me try to explain. You match `wmm` first and not `ww`. But after that you match `hh` and not `hmm`. `wmm` has lower priority than `ww`, but `hh` has higher priority than `hmm`. What is the reason for the difference in choice here?

Comment: It's because of the Items array. The combination of items there needs to be checked before Patterns. E.g `Items[1]` + `Items[2]` + `Items[3]` is perfect match of `Patterns[3]` so that should be prioritized over `ww`. What I’m saying is. If the Items combination matches with any Patterns combinations, those needs to be prioritized. If the combination of the Items array does not match any of the Patterns combinations, then match the prioritized Patterns (left to right) depending on the item.

Comment: Okay, I have tried something: http://jsfiddle.net/aJpeJ/. If it behaves correctly, I'll post it as an answer with explanation.

Comment: Amazing! This works great. Do you happen to know a solution how to wrap the last items up so they match any of the Patterns? I believe the last one or two needs to change from their current character to something else to match a pattern.

Comment: Do you want both of them to be changed to `l` so that they match?

Comment: The ultimate way would be that either combo at the end worked (not only this Items array). So, any item combination at the end would fit together.

Comment: Not quite sure. If there are two items left and all patterns are three characters long, then there's no solution.

Comment: The last combination does not need to match a Pattern completely. Just the 1-2-3 first characters.

Comment: Maybe you're after this: http://jsfiddle.net/aJpeJ/1/.

Comment: Thank you! Only thing is that it seems to add 'l' multiple times. There isnt an easy way to check the 1-2 last characters for a combination for the last item?

Comment: Hmm, do you mean the last letters should be joined to as large a pattern as possible?

Comment: Joined as the closest Pattern combination. Lets say the last two characters are `w` and `h`. This would end up be `ww` because the last two starts with `w` and the `h` changes to `w`. If the last three looked like this: `h`, `m`, `w` then the last would change to `m` because `hmm` is matches 'hmm'. Or last scenario, if the last two characters are `m`, `l` then the last (`l`) would change to `m` because `m` matches Patterns[4], Patterns[6], Patterns[7] and all these starts with `m` and continues with an `m` so, the last `l` would change to a `m`. Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/aJpeJ/4/. It's getting really dirty, though. Curious as to the use case :)

Comment: pimvdb, would you mind share your email? I would like to ask you something.

Comment: No, rather not, sorry :)

Comment: pimvdb, is it possible to know the ids of the Items array efter it has been rearranged based on the Patterns array? e.g lets say we have this Items array: l,m,w,m (0,1,2,3) and after rearranging it you get l,w,m,m (0,2,1,3). Is possible somehow to get the new arranged ids? (thanks so much for you help.)

Comment: If you map each item letter into an object like `{ letter: "l", id: 0 }`, and then swap the items around, then you could map each object into `obj.id` again. Anyway, discard the code I posted above, I only tested it with a few arrays and apparently it's full of errors...

Comment: I’ve added id to the Items object in your example, but I would like the Result array to somehow show the rearranged ids. Not sure how this is being done :S Is this even possible?

Comment: It should be pretty straight-forward; see http://jsfiddle.net/mHZpE/1/. The letters and IDs are aligned, because they were moved along with each other.

Comment: This is more or less how I imagine it would work, but I having a hard to figure out how to implement this into your http://jsfiddle.net/aJpeJ/1/ code. I would like to be able to know how the ids are rearranged. Is there a simple way? :P

Comment: Ignore that code, it has become one big mess. It actually appends the patterns when there is a match, and not the letters, so it's not very easy to implement that.